error when puplish alpha testing release in flutter using azure devops into google store
I am trying to publish alpha testing aab into google store but I am face this error
Error: invalid grant: Invalid grant: account not found


I am using actual userName of googleplay console and I certain that its correct
I am using google realease task and this is my code
task: 
ms-vsclient.google-play.google-play-
  release.GooglePlayRelease@4 displayName:
    'Releaseto alpha' inputs: serviceConnection: 
    'my_service_connection' applicationId: MyAppId
     bundleFile: i put mypath track: alpha 
     changeLogFile: i put mypath


This error occurs because your Azure pipeline is unable to find the google play service connection. Make sure you create a google play service connection with correct private key and use it in your task like below:-

Login to Developer console
Setup an API access
In the Service Accounts > Create New Service Connection > In a Service Accounts IAM & Admin page > Create Service account > Add the Service account name > ID and Description  > Add Owner role for the Service connection
Create the service connection and Add the Json Key for google service connection
Now, Copy this Key in Azure Devops Service connection below:-


Now use the Service connection in your google play release task like below:-

Complete Pipeline:-
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.x'
    addToPath: true

# Install Flutter
- task: UseFlutter@1
  inputs:
    version: 'stable'
    cache: true

# Get Flutter dependencies
- script: |
    flutter pub get
  displayName: 'Get Flutter Dependencies'

# Build the Flutter app for Android
- script: |
    flutter build appbundle --release
  displayName: 'Build Flutter App for Android'

# Publish build artifacts
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: 'build/app/outputs/bundle/release'
    artifact: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'

# Download build artifacts
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  displayName: 'Download Build Artifacts'
  inputs:
    artifactName: 'drop'
    downloadPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/drop'

# Release to Google Play alpha track
- task: GooglePlayRelease@4
  inputs:
    serviceConnection: 'GplayconnectionService'
    applicationId: 'xxxxx.myapp'
    action: 'SingleBundle'
    bundleFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/drop/app.aab'
    track: 'alpha'
    changeLogFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/drop/changelog.txt'

Reference taken from Configure Azure DevOps to distribute your Android application to Google Play Damien Aicheh

thank you  your propsal was great and the issue was solved   @SiddheshDesai
